# performance enhancement using flatMap vs for-comprehension

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, actor

I have an actor in my play app, that every tick (2 sec) sends a message to some method:

```
onSomething() : Future[Unit] = {
    for {
        a <- somethingThatReturnsFuture
        b <- anotherThingThatReturnsFuture
    }
}
```

This method has two calls that return future so I decided to use for-comprehension, but is it true that for-comprehension is blocking? So akka could not call this method again even with the 16 instances they run until the method complete?

If I would have my method to work with flatMap/map this will allow akka to have better performance? Like this:

```
onSomething() : Future[Unit] = {
    somethingThatReturnsFuture.flatMap(res1 => {
        anotherThingThatReturnsFuture.map(res2 => {
            //whatever
        })
    })
}
```

thanks

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

Answer (score 4):

As per Luis' comment, for-comprehensions are just **syntactic sugar**

> Scala’s “for comprehensions” are syntactic sugar for composition of
>   multiple operations with `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` or `withFilter`.
>   Scala actually translates a for-expression into calls to those
>   methods, so any class providing them, or a subset of them, can be used
>   with for comprehensions.

which expands into underlying monadic operations, thus there should be no performance hit over using monadic operations directly. If your methods are independent of each other then you might gain same performance by taking advantage of `Future`s being **eager** and start them outside the for-comprehension like so

```
val aF = somethingThatReturnsFuture()
val bF = anotherThingThatReturnsFuture() // I started without waiting on anyone 

for {
  a <- aF
  b <- bF
} yield { 
  a + b
}
```

However if calculation of `b` depends on `a` then you will not be able to kick them off in parallel

```
for {
  a <- somethingThatReturnsFuture
  b <- anotherThingThatReturnsFuture(a)
} yield { 
  a + b
}
```

Here `anotherThingThatReturnsFuture` "blocks" in the sense of having to wait on `somethingThatReturnsFuture`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all.
Because the methods you are calling return a Future, none of them will block the Thread execution.

But what it is true, is that flatmap will concatenate sequentially the two operations. I mean, it will call the first method, then it returns inmediately, because it is a Future, and then it will call the second.

This will happen in the two options you have posted before (for comprehension and flatmap) because they are basically the same.

If you want to call the two methods at the same time, (in two different threads), so you don't know which of them will start to execute first, you have to use parallel collections.

But in your case, perhaps it is better to not use them because using futures will guarante that the thread will not block